# Embed numpy in a zipapp archive

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to zip some sources in order to use it easily from multiple locations. I have to install some external modules, let us say *pyyaml* and *numpy*.

First, I install these packages in a specific location:

```
python -m pip install --target=lib pyyaml numpy
```

And then I create the zipped library:

```
python -m zipapp library --output=my_library.pyd --compress
```

In another interpreter, after adding "my_library.pyd" to the `sys.path`, I can load the `yaml` module, but not the `numpy` one:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> sys.path.append(str(Path().absolute() / 'my_library.pyd'))
>>> import yaml
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\rdpy\packaging_tests\my_library.pyd\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "D:\Documents\rdpy\packaging_tests\my_library.pyd\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "D:\Documents\rdpy\packaging_tests\my_library.pyd\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Documents\rdpy\packaging_tests\my_library.pyd\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
  File "D:\Documents\rdpy\packaging_tests\my_library.pyd\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using D:\Apps\python-3.7\python.exe),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

     Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
     an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

In the zip archive, I do have a file named `numpy\core\_multiarray_umath.cp37-win_amd64.pyd`, but it obviously is a C compiled file.

Is there anything I can do to be able and import numpy when creating the zip archive?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a problem with zipapp on import some .c compiled files. To solve this I used the [install creator](https://www.clickteam.com/install-creator-2). It was what I want, create a .exe from python code.